# ISBLANK returning an error

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

can anyone help me with this formula?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F3);"Aanwezig") ; IF(NOT(ISBLANK(F3));"Uitgeleend") ; IF(ISBLANK(H3);"Uitgeleend") ; IF(NOT(ISBLANK(H3));"Terug")
```

So I don't know how to explain it better... I hope its clear..

This is what is want, but it gives the `#VALUE!` error...
Im trying to use excel as a lending system.

Anyone give me the right formula? I'm stuck:(

Thanks!

Comment: Hello sir, please have a look on [How to ask questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide us some explanation of your issue. What have you tried so far to resolve your problem ?

Comment: I trying to make it look like this:

Comment: I trying to make it look like this: I have F3 for the date on which it was lent. H3 for the date the lent item comes back. I3 shows the outcome. If the date is filled in F3 it means the item is lent, so I3 show: "Lent", If not filled, it shows just nothing or "not lent" in I3. If the date is filled in H3 it means "the lent item is back", and if its not filled it means "item is lent".....better?

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at the `=IF()` syntax in [Excel from Microsoft support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2). When you start typing a function in Excel there is an help regarding the argument you are trying to input, do have a look there.

Comment: You need to work backwards with your conditions, at the moment it will never get passed whether F3 is blank or not, as they are the first two arguments.

Comment: No idea which words to use, but from your English description try `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(H3)), "Returned", IF(ISBLANK(F3), "", "Lent"))`

Comment: I second @TimWilkinson 's answer. And please, change the title of your question to something more understandable like: "Excel - IF() Function syntax issue"

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This was exactly what I meant:

Comment: No idea which words to use, but from your English description try =IF(NOT(ISBLANK(H3)), "Returned", IF(ISBLANK(F3), "", "Lent")) – Tim Wilkinson 1 hour ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work backwards as your current formula won't get past whether `F3` is blank or not, so check for `H3` first, then check `F3`.

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(H3)), "Returned", IF(ISBLANK(F3), "", "Lent"))
```

Comment: It depends on the system language because some languages like French and German have `;` separators while English for example has `,` separators for arguments.

Comment: Learn something new every day!

Comment: Whichever language uses decimal commas instead of decimal points, will have semicolon (;) separators.

Answer (score -2):

This is equivalent to writing a formula like this:

```
=if(F3="","Aanwezig","Uitgeleend")
```

This will return you either `"Aanwezig"` or `"Uitgeleend"` depending on whether or not cell `F3` is empty.

Comment: This completely ignores whether the `H3` is blank or not though?